# My table of contents is weird

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, tocloft, titletoc

I doing a template which I use tocloft for summary title and titletoc for summary body.
Well, I've just noticed that It isn't respecting the margin, so I dont know what to do now(find no error).
Could someone help me?

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}[abntex2]

%=========================================================

\usepackage[nobottomtitles]{titlesec}%Formatar titulos

\usepackage{tocloft}%formatar sumário

\usepackage{titletoc}%formatar sumario

%Formatar sumário
%===========================================titulo(centralizado, negrito, caixa alta)
%sumário

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0cm}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{1.5cm}
%===========================================================================
%secão

\titlecontents{section}[1.5cm]
{\vspace{.5cm}\bfseries}
{\contentslabel{1.5cm}}
{}
{\cftdotfill{0.1}\contentspage}
[]
%===========================================================================
%subseção

\titlecontents{subsection}[1.5cm]
{\vspace{.1cm}}
{\contentslabel{1.5cm}}
{}
{\cftdotfill{0.1}\contentspage}
[]
%===========================================================================

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[1.5cm]
{\vspace{.1cm}}
{\contentslabel{1.5cm}}
{}
{\cftdotfill{0.1}\contentspage}
[]
%===========================================================================
%seções

\newcommand{\secao}[1]{
\newpage

\section{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\label{sec:#1}
}
%subseção

\newcommand{\subsecao}[1]{
\subsection{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\label{subsec:#1}
}
%==================================================================
%subsubseção

\newcommand{\subsubsecao}[1]{
\subsubsection{#1}\label{subsubsec:#1}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\secao{dicas para organização}

\subsecao{distribuição}

\subsecao{paginas}
\secao{pré textual}

\subsecao{capa: titulo, autor, 
orientador, etc}

\subsecao{listas de ilustrações}

\subsubsecao{Lista de figuras}

\subsubsecao{Lista de quadros}

\subsubsecao{Lista de tabelas}

\subsubsecao{Outras listas deilustrações}

\subsecao{outras listas}

\subsubsecao{Lista de siglas}

\subsubsecao{Lista de abreviações}

\subsubsecao{Lista de símbolos}

\secao{textual}

\subsecao{citações}

\secao{títulos}

\subsecao{subtítulos}

\subsubsecao{Subsubtítulos}

\subsecao{referenciar seções}

\secao{pós textual}

\subsecao{referências}

\subsecao{glossário}

\subsecao{apêndices}

\subsecao{anexo}

\subsecao{índice}

\secao{something}

\secao{something}

\secao{something}

\secao{something}

\secao{something}

\secao{something}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you minimise your example by removing packages which don't cause the problem? You can do this by commenting things out and compiling. If the problem remains, you can remove them. If the problem disappears, uncomment them.

Comment: The problem lies in your declaration of `\titlecontents{section}`. Specifically with `\vspace{.5cm}`. Try removing it and compile it again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your declaration of `\titlecontents{section}`. Specifically with `\vspace{.5cm}`. Here's a better way to do it.

```
\titlecontents{section}[1.5cm]
{\bfseries}
{\contentslabel{1.5cm}}
{}
{\cftdotfill{0.1}\contentspage\vspace{.5cm}}
[]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't load both `tocloft` and `titletoc`, because they're fighting each other.

I don't recommend using `\secao`, but to reformat `\section` (and its siblings). I wouldn't use “automatic labels”, but I left the code for them. It's much better to use explicit `\label` commands with memorable arguments. In case you want to follow my advice, just replace

```
\TITLEAndLabel{sec}
\TITLEAndLabel{subsec}
\titleAndLabel{subsubsec}
```

with just `\MakeUppercase`. Also `\clearpage` is better than `\newpage`, because it flushes floats.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}[abntex2]
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nobottomtitles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

%Formatar sumário
\titlecontents{section}
  [1.5cm]
  {\vspace{.5cm}\bfseries}
  {\contentslabel{1.5cm}\MakeUppercase}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}
  [1.5cm]
  {\vspace{.1cm}}
  {\contentslabel{1.5cm}\MakeUppercase}
  {\MakeUppercase}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsubsection}
  [1.5cm]
  {\vspace{.1cm}}
  {\contentslabel{1.5cm}}
  {}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

% sections
\newcommand{\TITLEAndLabel}[2]{%
  \MakeUppercase{#2}\label{#1:#2}%
}
\newcommand{\titleAndLabel}[2]{%
  #2\label{#1:#2}%
}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\newpage\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {\TITLEAndLabel{sec}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
  {\clearpage\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {\TITLEAndLabel{subsec}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\thesubsubsection}
  {1em}
  {\titleAndLabel{subsubsec}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{dicas para organização}

\subsection{distribuição}

\subsection{paginas} \section{pré textual}

\subsection{capa: titulo, autor, orientador, etc}

\subsection{listas de ilustrações}

\subsubsection{Lista de figuras}

\subsubsection{Lista de quadros}

\subsubsection{Lista de tabelas}

\subsubsection{Outras listas deilustrações}

\subsection{outras listas}

\subsubsection{Lista de siglas}

\subsubsection{Lista de abreviações}

\subsubsection{Lista de símbolos}

\section{textual}

\subsection{citações}

\section{títulos}

\subsection{subtítulos}

\subsubsection{Subsubtítulos}

\subsection{referenciar seções}

\section{pós textual}

\subsection{referências}

\subsection{glossário}

\subsection{apêndices}

\subsection{anexo}

\subsection{índice}

\section{something}

\section{something}

\section{something}

\section{something}

\section{something}

\section{something}

\end{document}
```

I also loaded `brazil-babel`.

[image]

Comment: Well, i need toc title to be in boldfont and centered, do you know how I do that without tocloft?

Comment: @Leonidas `\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
  {\clearpage\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\MakeUppercase}` That is, add `\filcenter`.